# Open Appended URL in New Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a hub that allows me to put in a ticket number which is then appended to a URL so it opens directly in a ticketing system. I have this working. The final step is to have the ticketing system open in a separate tab.

Code

```
<form id="srs">
    <input id="srbcp" name="srbcp" type="text">
    <input type="button" onclick="pullsr('window.open')" value="Submit">
</form>


<script>

}

function pullsr() {

  var action_src = $("#srbcp").val();
  var srs = $("#srs");
  var urlLink = "https://xxxxxxx.com/SR/";
  var urlLink = urlLink + action_src;
  console.log(urlLink);
  location.href = urlLink;

 }

 </script>
```

Comment: Use MDN artical for window.open : Answer is simple but it may help you to know more varieties of using this method :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
location.href = urlLink;
```

to

```
var win = window.open(urlLink, '_blank');
win.focus();
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `window.open`

Below is the code

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script><form id="srs">
    <input id="srbcp" name="srbcp" type="text">
    <input type="button" onclick="pullsr()" value="Submit">
</form>


<script>

function pullsr() {

  var action_src = $("#srbcp").val();
  var srs = $("#srs");
  var urlLink = "https://xxxxxxx.com/SR/";
  var urlLink = urlLink + action_src;
  console.log(urlLink);
  //location.href = urlLink;
  window.open(urlLink, "_blank");

 }

 </script>
```